# List all data in html with Thymeleaf & Spring

Tags: spring, list, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf & Spring EMERGENCY! How to get data inside HTML.

Controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/")
public String showRegisterForm(DentistVisitDTO dentistVisitDTO) {
    dentistVisitService.listVisits();
    return "form";
}
```

Method listVisits:

```java
@ModelAttribute("listVisits")
public List<DentistVisitEntity> listVisits() {
    return dentistVisitDao.getAllVisits();
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr th:each="listVisit : ${listVisits}">
  <td th:text="${listVisit.id}">1</td>
  <td><a href="#" th:text="${listVisit.dentistName}">Title ...</a></td>
  <td th:text="${listVisit.visitTime}">Text ...</td>
</tr>
```

Currently it doesn't show anything in HTML! STUCK!

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you'd need to add your elements to the model with something like:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String showRegisterForm(DentistVisitDTO dentistVisitDTO, 
                               Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listVisits", dentistVisitService.listVisits());
    return "form";
}
```